# MinMax custom Layer Tensor Flow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, layer

I am working on a deep learning model for image classification. I am trying to use Min Max scaler to scale my images, I already used `layers.Rescaling()` and `layers.BatchNormalization()` , i am just trying to compare result.

To do so, i have to build a custom layer but it doesn't seem to work, already tried many ways and the images turn out all black. I really don't know what is wrong, it is my first time working with tensorflow and keras.

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

# custom layer with MinMaxScaler 
class MinMaxScalerSKLayer(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, feature_range=(0,1), **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.feature_range = feature_range
        
    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=self.feature_range)
        super().build(input_shape)
        
    def call(self, inputs):
        shape = inputs.shape
        flattened_inputs = tf.reshape(inputs, (shape[0], -1))
        flattened_inputs_scaled = self.scaler.fit_transform(flattened_inputs)
        inputs_scaled = tf.reshape(flattened_inputs_scaled, shape)
        return inputs_scaled


minmax_sk = Sequential([
    MinMaxScalerSKLayer()], 
name='minmax_sk')
```

I suspect it has something to do with flatten the images so it can scale all the dimension, but I don't know.

Comment: Why do you want min-max scale in a layer and not as part of the preprocessing pipeline? Also images have defined value range of 0 to 255, so you can divide the images with 255 to obtain a range from 0 to 1.

Comment: @Plagon it is part of the preprocessing pipeline, but i want to see how it looks like. Applying the layers.Rescaling(1./255) also turns the images all black, i dont know why, but for example  layers.Rescaling(1./2) doesn't, why i think is weird